# If logic in python

Tags: python

I have a quick question regarding if logic in python. I have the following code:

```
    def punch(self):
        """Punch method that returns different remarks based on glove weight"""

        if self.weight < 5:
            return "That tickles."
        elif self.weight >= 5 & self.weight < 15:
            return "Hey that hurt!"
        else:
            return "OUCH!"
```

When I run the following code it always returns “Hey that hurt!”, no matter what weight I assign to self.weight. I am extremely confused as to why that is.

Comment: Instead of using `&`, what happens if you use `and`? Also, instead of using `|`, what happens if you use `or`? [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) is a little more information from the documentation, if it helps! I think `&` [means something different](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) than what you might have been expecting, for Python.

Comment: Your question talks about assert statements (which are in fact an actual thing in Python), whereas you have shown if statements. Please stick to standard terminology, this is confusing.

Comment: There's no assert here.

Comment: Where exactly did you get the idea to use `&`, was it in some tutorial? You almost certainly intended to use the boolean `and` operator instead. (`&` is the bitwise AND).

Comment: I honestly didn't know the difference between the two which has now been clarified. My question is why does adding partheses change the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&`, `|`, etc. are `bitwise` operators, used for things like bit-flipping, etc.

`and`, `or`, `not`, etc. are logical operators, and are what you likely mean to use in situations like these.

Also, as a side note, `assert`, as you've called it in the title, is something else entirely from logic statements like the ones you've presented.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between the two operators in Python: `&` (bitwise AND) and `and` (boolean AND). `&` has a higher precedence than `and` which is why your code behaves differently. Learn more about operator precedence [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, I think you would want to use the terms `and` or `or` instead of `&` and `|` for what it looks you are wanting to do.

In this particular language, `&` and `|` appear to be [bitwise operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) instead of [boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), like I was getting at in my earlier comments.